# Additional parameters while using Freeform Pro Fieldtype

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm trying to use the [Freefrom Pro](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) Fieldtype in a channel to select the correct form within an entry. I'd like to add `form:class="well"` and `inline_errors="yes"` for all the forms rendered with that Freeform fieldtype short name in the `channel:entries` tag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using composer? You could make a new composer template (which automatically starts you with the default composer template tag, etc, so you don't have to start from scratch) and you can add custom params there in the template area: http://cl.ly/image/3X3N2A2i3A0L

Then, in the upper left hand corner in composer itself, choose the new composer template and save.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm: in your entry you select a form (Freeform fieldtype) that is then displayed in your template, and you want to pass some parameters to it?

You can just add these parameters to your field. Say your field is "event_form" and you want to pass inline errors and form class to it: {event_form inline_errors="yes" form:class="registration_form"}

Comment: Good to know this. I can't see any mention of parameters on a single tag in the docs. Unfortunately not all of them work, error templates don't. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19228/freeform-pro-channel-entry-fieldtype-custom-error-page