# Freeform Pro - Channel Entry Fieldtype - Custom error page

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

This is partially related to this question:
[Additional parameters while using Freeform Pro Fieldtype](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13126/additional-parameters-while-using-freeform-pro-fieldtype)

I can't see these options in the Freeform docs, but it seems if you add parameters to the single tag some do output.
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/channel_entry_fieldtype/

Eg. short name of field is channel_field

```
{channel_field}
```

To add a custom class name to all forms in the template:

```
{channel_field form:class="your_class_name"}
```

This outputs the form from composer including the custom class name.

Parameters for the form tag pair are here, including the option of a custom error page:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#error_page

But this does not work:

```
{channel_field error_page="path_to/template"}
```

How can I specify a custom error page while using the freeform field type?

This question is directed at Solspace, but it would be great if anyone else could help.

** Edit 11 Feb 2014 **
Thanks @Solspace. I'd forgotten I've actually set this up already. I have a custom Composer Template assigned to this form with these Template Params:

- Param Name: error_page
- Param Value: site/form-error

But I hadn't realised this custom page was working as the error page URL is:
    `http://example.co.uk/?ACT=72`

Rather than:
    `http://example.co.uk/form-error/`

It looks like you're handling the error template display during a form submission method and not redirecting?

Now I know where the error page is coming from I've got an unrelated issue why this isn't working. I'll raise a support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually get the raw form_id from the fieldtype tag like this:

```
{channel_field:form_id}
```

You can use that inside a regular `{exp:freeform:form}` tag as a parameter, which should allow you access to all of the params of freeform:form. I've done this once before. I don't recall if you need embeds/stash to get around parse order issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a **custom Composer Template** to go with your Composer form, you can set the same parameters as used  by `{exp:freeform:form}`. From the in-add-on instructions:

> **Template Params**
>   Add default tag params composer output. These can be any parameters available to {exp:freeform:form}.
>   *These will override anything set by Freeform Composer.*

**Additional information**: The Composer templates are created in Freeform from the "*Composer Templates*" tab, and a custom Composer Template is associated with your Composer form in the top left dropdown in the Composer Editor UI in the CP ("*Forms*" tab).

Comment: I've amended the original question above with a response.